# How to receive data from webapp on telegraf bot

Tags: node.js, reactjs, grammy

How to receive data or event from webapp on telegraf.

I used grammy inlinekeyboard to open webapp.
I made webapp with react.
I don't know how to send data from webapp and receive it on bot.

Here is my code.

```
import { InlineKeyboard } from "grammy";

const keyboard =  new InlineKeyboard()
.text('Social', 'social')
.webApp('Deposit/Withdraw', 
    `https://weehodl-web.netlify.app/wallets`
);

bot.start(async ctx => {
  ctx.reply('i am bot', {reply_markup: keyboard});
});
```